# Get Gridview cell value on cell click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview having as an sqldatasource a stored procedure. The stored procedure creates a matrix table. I want when I click on a cell of the gridview to display the value of this specific cell to a popup window.
My gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" /><FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /></asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cntest %>" 
        SelectCommand="test_matrix" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="59" Name="SelectIdvar" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="dateid" SessionField="DateId" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Where you want Client side or server side ?

Comment: Use javascript/jquery: `$('#GridView1 td').on('click',function(){alert($(this).html());})`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like server side and save the result to a string also.

Answer (score 0):

Try with writing Custom event for the Gridview Cell click and write javascript to show the popup on the cell click event of the gridview.

**Sample Javascript:**

```
ScriptManager
.RegisterStartupScript(
  this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", window.open(Target,'height=400,width=800,status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,location=1,scrollbars=1'
), true);
```